# 'System.IO.MemoryStream' does not contain a definition 'for'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments, vcf-vcard

I am having a little problem here.

> Error1 'System.IO.MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for
>   'CopyTo'

My Code:

```
// Error occurs here (CopyTo) (For Framework 4.0)
ms.CopyTo(actualAttachment);    
actualAttachment.Position = 0;  

//Change CopyTo to WriteTo For Framework 2.0
ms.WriteTo(actualAttachment);   
actualAttachment.Position = 0;
```

I had to retype my whole code to make sure everything goes into a stream, because I had some problems with deleting a file after it's being send. but now I get this error.

So basically it shouldn't save anything now.

I simply didn't paid attention on what framework I was using.
I work with 4 types of frameworks a day which sometimes really confuses me.

Comment: er, because `MemoryStream` has no `CopyTo` method.

Comment: @Rafael: The `CopyTo` method was introduced in .NET Framework 4. Are you using an earlier one?

Comment: framework version? Client profile ?

Comment: Programming Goose lal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which framework version are you using? That method is only available since version 4 of the framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's pretty stupid. I am using 2.0 today at school. and 4.5 at home.

Comment: @Rafael - Its not stupid, the .NET Framework has been updated, the method didn't exists in earlier versions.  The simple solution use the same version at both locations.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
attach = new Attachment(actualAttachment, ContentType);
```

inside the using brackets for the StreamWriter and change it to

```
ms.Position = 0;
attach = new Attachment(ms, ContentType);
```

You can then get rid of the MemoryStream actualAttachment.

You are already putting the data in a memory stream via the StreamWriter, just use it instead.

Comment: What is the definition of CopyTo (from framework 4.0) in framework 2.0 then?

Comment: @Rafael - Explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

`ms.WriteTo(actualAttachment);`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

changed

```
 ms.CopyTo(actualAttachment);
 actualAttachment.Position = 0;
```

to

```
 ms.WriteTo(actualAttachment);
 actualAttachment.Position = 0;
```

Solved the problem. 
Thanks to everybody trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this particular error.
My project was targeted for 3.5 framework.
Error   8   'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and no extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Stream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my code :

> Stream inputStream = Request.InputStream;
>
> FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
>
> inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

i changed project settings > ASP.net configuration > target framework to 4.0
and it reopened. It worked. thanks